# How do i make it so second sproc doesn't run until first sproc is finished?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute a sproc to insert a set of records in two tables and then, once all records are inserted, execute another sproc.  It seems from everything I can find that this should work fine as sprocs should run sequentially and asynchronously.  However, my results seem to say different.

If I execute the first sproc and and then manually execute the second sproc.  I get the results I want.  But if I execute both sprocs in one script as below, I get a different result set.

```
      Exec sp1
           @variable1 = ...
           @ariable2 = ....

      Exec sp2 (no variable passing required)
```

First Procedure (left off some update steps for clarity)

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GenerateARInvoiceOriginalBU]
  @workorderid int
 ,@clientpo varchar(50) 
 ,@invoicenumber varchar(15)
 ,@invoicedate date
 ,@accountingdate date
as begin

-- insert invoice ----------
insert invoices(customer,job,invoicedate,accountingdate,invoicenumber,isquote,quoteexpiry,description,pretax,tax,posted)
select j.jarcust,j.job,@invoicedate,@accountingdate,@invoicenumber,0,null,'',0,0,0 
from workorders w
join jobs j on w.job=j.job
where w.workorderid=@workorderid

-- insert invoice items ----------   
insert invoiceitems
(invoiceid,workorderid,workorderdescription,extra,extradescription,itemid,itemdescription,clientpo
,qty,price,uom,pretax,tax,taxgroup,taxrate,costcode,revenueaccount,holdbackpcnt
,billedqty,billedpretax,billedpercent,contractqty,contractprice,contractpretax)
select ident_current('invoices') invoiceid,e.workorderid,w.description workorderdesc,e.extra,e.description extradesc,0 itemid,e.description itemdesc,e.clientpo
      ,e.qty
      ,e.price,'' uom
      ,e.pretax 
      ,e.tax
      ,e.taxgroup,e.taxrate,e.costcode,e.revenueaccount,e.holdbackpcnt
      ,e.qtybilled,e.pretaxbilled,0 billedpercent,e.qty,e.price,e.pretax
  from workorders w
      inner join workorderextras e on (w.workorderid=e.workorderid)
where ISNULL(e.costcode,'')<>''
  and ISNULL(e.pretax,0)<>0
  and ISNULL(e.pretaxbilled,0)=0
  and w.workorderid=@workorderid
  and ISNULL(e.clientpo,'')=ISNULL(@ClientPO,'')
union all
select ident_current('invoices'),i.workorderid,max(w.description) workorderdesc,i.extra,max(e.description) extradesc,i.itemid,i.description itemdesc,i.clientpo
      ,e.qty*i.qty qty
      ,i.price,i.uom
      ,i.pretax
      ,i.tax
      ,i.taxgroup,i.taxrate,i.costcode,i.revenueaccount,i.holdbackpcnt
      ,i.qtybilled,i.pretaxbilled,0 billedpercent,e.qty*i.qty,i.price,i.pretax
  from workorders w
      inner join workorderextras e on (w.workorderid=e.workorderid)
      inner join workorderitems i on (e.workorderid=i.workorderid and e.extra=i.extra)
      left outer join completedtasks ct on i.workorderid=ct.workorderid and i.taskcode=ct.taskcode
where (ISNULL(i.taskcode,'')='' or ISNULL(ct.taskcode,'')<>'')
  and ISNULL(e.costcode,'')=''
  and ISNULL(i.pretax,0)<>0
  and ISNULL(i.pretaxbilled,0)=0
  and w.workorderid=@workorderid
  and ISNULL(i.clientpo,'')=ISNULL(@ClientPO,'')
group by w.arcustomer,i.workorderid,i.extra,i.itemid,i.description,i.clientpo,e.qty*i.qty,i.qtybilled,i.pretax,i.tax,i.pretaxbilled,i.taxgroup,i.taxrate,i.costcode,i.revenueaccount,i.holdbackpcnt,i.price,i.uom
order by 1,2,5

-- set invoice amount ---------- 
update invoices 
set pretax= (select sum(pretax) from invoiceitems where invoiceid=ident_current('invoices'))
   ,tax   = (select sum(tax) from invoiceitems where invoiceid=ident_current('invoices'))
from invoices
where invoiceid=ident_current('invoices')
```

Second Procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Generate_AR_Invoice_Combine]
as 
begin

update invoices set pretax=a.Pretax, tax=a.tax, oldid=1 from
CombineInvoices a where invoices.invoiceid=a.invoiceid
;
update invoiceitems
set invoiceid = cimi.mininvoiceid
from invoiceitems ii 
join combineinvoiceitems cii on ii.InvoiceItemID = cii.invoiceitemid
join dbo.combine_inv_items_min_invoice cimi on cii.job = cimi.job
--;
update invoices 
set combine=1 where isnull(combine,0) = '0' and oldid = '1'
;
delete from invoices where isnull(combine,0)=0 and isnull(oldid,0)=0
end
```

Here are the views used in the second procedure.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CombineInvoices]
AS
SELECT        MIN(i.InvoiceID) AS InvoiceID, MIN(i.InvoiceNumber) AS InvoiceNumber, i.Job, dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums.Pretax, dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums.Tax
FROM            dbo.Invoices AS i INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums ON i.Job = dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums.Job
WHERE        (ISNULL(i.Combine, 0) = 0)
GROUP BY i.Job, dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums.Pretax, dbo.Combine_Inv_Items_Sums.Tax

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CombineInvoiceItems]
AS
SELECT        i.Job, ii.InvoiceItemID, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceID
FROM            dbo.Invoices AS i INNER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceItems AS ii ON i.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID
WHERE        (ISNULL(i.Combine, '') = 0)
GROUP BY i.Job, ii.InvoiceItemID, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceID

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Combine_Inv_Items_Sums]
AS
SELECT        cii.Job, ROUND(SUM(ii.Pretax), 2) AS Pretax, ROUND(SUM(ii.Tax), 2) AS Tax
FROM            dbo.CombineInvoiceItems AS cii INNER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceItems AS ii ON cii.InvoiceItemID = ii.InvoiceItemID
GROUP BY cii.Job

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Combine_Inv_Items_Min_Invoice]
AS
SELECT        MIN(InvoiceID) AS MinInvoiceid, Job
FROM            dbo.CombineInvoiceItems
GROUP BY Job
```

In a simple example, here is the data set created in the two sprocs run separately (this normally runs on much more data but works the same).

[Data from sproc 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoZvQ.png)

Notice that each invoiceitemid is associated with a different invoiceid.  I then execute sproc 2 and get the following results.

[Data from sproc 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVIae.png)

Now all the invoiceitemid's are associated with a single invoiceid and the extra invoiceid's have been deleted.  Also, oldid and combine are set to 1 to avoid these items being manipulated in this procedure when run later.  This is the result I want.

However, if I call both sprocs as I noted above instead of running separately, I get the following results.

[Data from running the sproc's sequentially in one script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNSh9.png)

Note that the invoiceitemid's remain associated with separate invoiceid's and the 'oldid' and 'combine' fields are set to 1 for all instead of being combined to one invoice.

The only way i can figure this happening is if sproc2 is being executed every time sproc 1 inserts a record.

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to correct this where i can still have the two sprocs run sequentially without having to manually execute the second sproc.

Comment: Either way should work. You need to provide more infomration. How does the 2nd procedure determine which records to process. That is where the problem is, not in the way you call the stored procedures.

Comment: I've added some further info.  Appreciate any advice.  I also thought it should work as is.

Comment: You don't happen to have any triggers defined on your tables do you?

Comment: Just looked and did find these two triggers.  Would these cause it to work differently?  They are put in place by previous programmer so I would have to review if their purpose is still valid for our needs.  If they do effect it and are needed, could I temporarily stop them from triggering?

Comment: ALTER trigger [dbo].[STMP_Workorders] ON [dbo].[Workorders] for update as update Workorders set ModifiedDate=getdate() from Workorders a join inserted b on a.WorkorderID=b.WorkorderID

Comment: ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[STMP_WorkorderItems] ON [dbo].[WorkorderItems] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON


update workorderitems set PretaxBilled=0, QtyBilled=0 where PretaxBilled<>0 and pretaxbilled<1 
update WorkorderItems set ModifiedDate=getdate(), tax=round(b.pretax*.05,2) from WorkorderItems a join inserted b on a.ItemID=b.ItemID
where b.taxgroup='AB + GST'

Comment: I did temporarily disable those triggers and tried again with the same issues.

Comment: Do check the important tables (`Invoices` and `InvoiceItems`) before sproc1, in between and after sproc2, one time executing the sprocs one by one and on time run sequentially in the same script. Take a look at `JobId`s

Comment: I have tried multiple suggestions and ideas to correct this problem.  No matter what I do, it is the same result.  If i run the two procedures separately, the results are what i expect.  If I call them sequentially from another sp, the results are incorrect.  I have tried a waitfor delay, a while loop using a record counter, etc. to no avail.  All advice says they will operate sequentially and results should be the same whether I call them separately or call them one after the other from another sp.  However, that is not what happens for some reason.  I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: I now know what the issue is but not how to fix it.  It has to do with one of the variables being passed multiple values.  I will ask a new question on the proper topic in a new thread and close this thread.